# Using timer and game loop

Tags: c#

I'm building a simple console game, there is the player who moves *when key press down*, and there are enemies which moves *automatically, each type of enemy moves one time in X miliseconds*.

As I understood I should using the `timer`, but I don't really know how to do that in the game loop (isn't built yet because I don't know how to do with the timer. but it should be `while loop` I think). the game ends when the enemy 'touch' the player (same x and y).

One important thing: I can't you in this exercise in `Thread`, but if you have other suggestions instead of using `Timer` you are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: With console game, do you mean an application running on a videogame console or an actual console application? (command prompt etc)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You normally don't use conventional timers in games. Games have a very different mechanism for handling their logic and the time that passed, they normally don't work with timers or not in the way you would expect:

Games normally have something called a game loop. Generally speaking it's three main functions that are called one after the other in a loop:

```
while(running)
{
    HandleUserInput();
    ChangeWorld();
    Render();
}
```

You get user input, you change the game world accordingly and you draw it to the screen. Now, the faster your computer is, the faster this loop runs. That's good for the graphics (think FPS), but bad for the game. Imagine Tetris where every frame the blocks move. Now I would not want to buy a faster computer, the game would get more difficult that way.

So to keep the game speed constant independent of the power of the computer, the loop considers the time passed:

```
while(running)
{
    var timePassedSinceLastLoop = CalculateTimeDelta();

    HandleUserInput();
    ChangeWorld(timePassedSinceLastLoop);
    Render();
}
```

Now imagine a cooldown for something in game. The player pressed "a", some cool action happened and although he may press "a" again, nothing will happen for the next 5 seconds. But the game still runs and does all the other things that may happen ingame. This is not a conventional timer. It's a variable, lets call it ActionCooldown, and once the player triggers the action, it's set to 5 seconds. Every time the world changes, the timePassed is subtracted from that number until it's zero. All the time, the game is running and handling input and rendering. But only once ActionCooldown hits zero, another press of "a" will trigger that action again.

The ChangeWorld method includes all automatic changes to the world. Enemies, missiles, whatever moves without player interaction. And It moves based on time. If the enemy moves one square per second, You need to make his coordinate a float and add a fraction of a square every time the loop is run.

Lets say you have 30 fps so your loop runs 30 times a second. Your enemy now needs to move  1/30 of a square each loop. Then it will in the end have moved one full square per second.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I calculate the time? how do I know when an enemy needs to move? I tried with `timer` but it doesnt seem good because it isn't accurate.

Comment: To start really simple, you can take `DateTime.Now` every loop and find the timespan between them. Each enemy has a speed and you need to add it's speed to it's position every frame. If the speed is measured in blocks per second, you need to make sure you only add a fraction of the speed to the current position because only a fraction of a second has passed. What the speed of your enemy is, is your design decision.

Comment: I know this is really old, but I would strongly recommend using `DateTime.UtcNow` as `DateTime.Now` is expensive. Since you are only needing to calculate the time that has passed, you can use `UtcNow` which doesn't do any timezone offset math to determine what timezone the returned `DateTime` needs to be in. Bit more efficient for something along these lines.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

**The general premise behind the timer is to repeat some code every n.**

***To create the timer use this:***

```
 System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
         aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
         // Set the Interval to 1 millisecond.  Note: Time is set in Milliseconds
         aTimer.Interval=1;
         aTimer.Enabled=true;
```

**Then you implement this method:**

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
        //Whatever you need repeated
     }
```

**The full example can be found here:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx