# SFML RenderWindow wont open in splashscreen

Tags: c++, game-engine, sfml

I'm trying to display a splashscreen for 5 seconds in SFML 2.1, the display shows in the main gameloop, but in the init method, nothing shows, the icons shows for 5 seconds on the dock, but no window...

```
int initGame(){
    gameState = GAME_LOADING;
    // Create the main window
    window.create(mainVideoMode, "SFML Window", sf::Style::Default);
    // Set the Icon
    if (!icon.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "icon.png")) {
        gameState = GAME_EXIT;
    }
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "splashscreen.png"))
    {
        gameState = GAME_EXIT;
    }
    window.setIcon(icon.getSize().x, icon.getSize().y, icon.getPixelsPtr());
    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();

    // Create a graphical text to display
    /*if (!font.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "sansation.ttf")) {         If Needed
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }*/

    sf::sleep(sf::seconds(5));
    gameState = GAME_PLAYING;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a basic game loop and you need to replace your sleep call with a timer construct that is fit for games. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440555/using-timer-and-game-loop/17440807#17440807) for a detailed answer.

Whatever happens in your game, may never impact the game loop cycle of input/update/render. If you want to not accept input and not update for 5 seconds, great. But you need that loop to run.

PseudoCode because I don't have a compiler at hand:

```
variable timePassed = 0 seconds;

while(window is open && timePassed < 5 seconds)
{
    timePassed += the time that passed since the last loop

    window.clear();
    window.draw(splashscreen);
    window.display();
}
```